# Catch the click event on class inside SVG in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, svg

In my Angular 9 app I need to add the svg file as an interactive image.

The svg itself is in `my-file.svg` and looks like this:

```
<svg>
    <polygon class="my-polygon-class" points="31.7793,138.705 39.7885,138.705 39.7885,128.848 31.7793,128.848 "/>
    <!-- lots of other polygons and paths -->
</svg>
```

I have a component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'car-view',
  templateUrl: './car-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./car-view.component.scss']
})
export class CarViewComponent {
    constructor() {
    }

    elementClicked() {
    }
}
```

And in the `car-view.component.html` I include this svg as:

```
<div class="car-view">
    <object data="../assets/my-file.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</div>
```

How can I call the `elementClicked()` function inside `CarViewComponent` on click event on `my-polygon-class` (which is inside the svg)? I also need to toggle another class (say `element-clicked`) in order to mark the svg polygon as clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add it in this way

```
<div (click)='elementClicked()'>
<svg>
    <polygon class="my-polygon-class" points="31.7793,138.705 39.7885,138.705 39.7885,128.848 31.7793,128.848 "/>
    <!-- lots of other polygons and paths -->
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: That's one way to go, yes, but my svg file is about 500 rows and I'm going to need it in multiple components. I need to find a way to include this svg to the template as a separate file/template/etc and not copy and paste the content's of the svg all over the app

Comment: do you need click on every svg??

Comment: yes,I need it to be clickable in all the component I add it to.

Comment: you can create this as a separate component and just add its selector everywhere, also put some input property like data to this if you want to  do something with data on its click

Comment: Why does `elementClicked()` have no parameters? I am thinking of `elementClicked($event)`, but surely you somehow have to know ***which *** element was clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing create a component and provide template url as url of this svg. then on click output the event to parent component. For eg :-

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-svg-files-as-component-templates-with-angular-cli-ea58fe79b6c1

```
<polygon class="my-polygon-class" points="31.7793,138.705 39.7885,138.705 39.7885,128.848 31.7793,128.848 " (click)="elementClicked()"/>
```

Comment: `(click)="elementClicked()"` breaks the svg. `onclick="elementClicked()"` doesn't break the svg itself, but elementClicked() function seems to be out of scope

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: do one thing create a component and provide template url as url of this svg. then on click output the event to parent component. For eg :- https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-svg-files-as-component-templates-with-angular-cli-ea58fe79b6c1

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't work for me, because I have lot's of other stuff in the html template apart from that svg. That's why I need to include is as a separate image/file/template/etc